# How to make a screen that show a specific page if there's data to display and show a specific page if there's no data to display

Tags: flutter, dart

I made 3 dart file that called Cart, CartSection, and EmptyCartState.
here is the code from Cart

```
class CartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CartPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CartPageState createState() => _CartPageState();
}

class _CartPageState extends State<CartPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

it's still empty.
what I want to know is how to make this Cart show CartSection if there are something in the cart and show EmptyCartState if there is nothin in the cart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you like to get empty screen, you can use nullable data. I am using `int` as datatype, you can use your model in this case.

```dart
class CartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CartPage({
    Key? key,
    this.data,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int? data;

  @override
  _CartPageState createState() => _CartPageState();
}

class _CartPageState extends State<CartPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.data == null
        ? Text("empty data widget")
        : Text("cart data widget");
  }
}
```

Visit [dart.dev](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) to learn more about it.

Comment: it helps me a lot. thx a lot, man.

Comment: you can check that link to learn more about nullable data